# encountered `zig compiler bug: GenericPoison`?

Tags: zig

## Platform details

- macOS (Apple Silicon)
- zig versions (behavior identical on all)

  - 0.10.0 aarch64
  - 0.11-dev824 aarch64

## Problem

I wrote this code for basic composable iterators:

```
pub fn RangeIterator(comptime NumberType: type) type {
    return struct {
        const This = @This();
        const Item = NumberType;

        start: NumberType,
        step: NumberType,
        len: usize,
        _index: usize = 0,

        fn next(this: *This) !?Item {
            if (this._index >= this.len) {
                return null;
            }
            defer this._index += 1;
            return this.start + (this.step * @intCast(NumberType, this._index));
        }
    };
}

test "range iterator" {
    // these tests pass!
    var iterator = RangeIterator(u32){.start = 1, .step = 3, .len = 5};
    
    try std.testing.expectEqual(iterator.next(), 1);
    try std.testing.expectEqual(iterator.next(), 4);
    try std.testing.expectEqual(iterator.next(), 7);
    try std.testing.expectEqual(iterator.next(), 10);
    try std.testing.expectEqual(iterator.next(), 13);
    try std.testing.expectEqual(iterator.next(), null);
}

// based on pattern used for BufferedWriter & bufferedWriter
// https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/master/lib/std/io/buffered_writer.zig

pub fn IterWhile(
    comptime IteratorType: type,
    comptime ItemType: type,
    comptime include_last: bool,
) type {
    return struct {
        const This = @This();
        const Item = ItemType;

        iterator: IteratorType,
        predicate: fn (ItemType) bool,
        _is_spent: bool = false,

        pub fn next(this: *This) ?ItemType {
            if (this._is_spent) {
                return null;
            }

            const result = try this.iterator.next();
            if (result == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (!this.predicate(result)) {
                this._is_spent = true;
                if (!include_last) return null;
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
}

pub fn iterWhile(
    iterator: anytype,
    predicate: fn (anytype) bool,
    comptime include_last: bool,
) IterWhile(
    @TypeOf(iterator),
    @typeInfo(predicate).Fn.args[0].arg_type,
    include_last,
) {
    return .{ .iterator = iterator, .predicate = predicate };
}

test "iter while" {
    // these tests generate a compiler error :S
    var range = RangeIterator(u32){.start = 1, .step = 3, .len = 5};
    var iterator = iterWhile(range, TestUtils.isOneDigit, false);

    try std.testing.expectEqual(iterator.next(), 1);
    try std.testing.expectEqual(iterator.next(), 4);
    try std.testing.expectEqual(iterator.next(), 7);
    try std.testing.expectEqual(iterator.next(), null);
}

const TestUtils = struct {
    fn isOneDigit(value: u32) bool {
        return value < 10;
    }
};
```

If I comment out the second test block `"iter while"`, the tests pass. But if I leave them in, I get the following error:

```
thread 1531026 panic: zig compiler bug: GenericPoison
Unable to dump stack trace: debug info stripped
zsh: abort      zig test src/utils/iterator.zig
```

## Questions

1. Any ideas on what the problem is with the code? Edit: Or is this an issue with the compiler?
2. `debug info stripped` -> why is that happening? Aren't I running this in debug mode by not passing any of [the release build flags](https://ziglearn.org/chapter-3/#build-modes)?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/12373) or create a new issue in the bug tracker. I believe such questions aren't suitable for SO.

Comment: I disagree; I think SO is a good place to ask the general Zig user community if I’m making a user error, before I go to GitHub and tell the maintainers about a problem with their product.

Comment: But it sounds like you’re not aware of a particular user error in my code. Thanks for confirming that 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the error message is due to a bug in the compiler, there are some bugs in your code that when resolved allow the code to compile and run as expected:

1. (causing the GenericPoison compiler bug): `fn(u32) bool` is not assignable to `fn(anytype) bool`. `anytype` is a special value that can be used in arguments to specify that the argument should be generic and make a new copy of the function for every different type passed in. Changing `predicate: fn(anytype) bool` → `predicate: anytype` fixes this issue

After this, the rest of the issues have proper error messages (although some of the next ones will not display in color and note that there is a zig compiler bug related to their display: `Zig compiler bug: attempted to destroy declaration with an attached error`)

2. `@typeInfo(predicate)` - predicate is of type `fn(u32) bool` here, so you need to use `@TypeOf`: `@typeInfo(@TypeOf(predicate))`
3. `.arg_type` - this is an optional. a null value means that the argument type is set to `anytype`. Use `.arg_type.?` here. Note that in newer versions of zig, this is changed to `.Fn.params[0].type.?`
4. `predicate: fn(ItemType) bool` - this is causing the struct to be comptime-only. To make it available at runtime, use a function pointer: `*const fn(ItemType) bool` and `.predicate = &predicate`. The error message on this one is not very helpful - it says the function is being called at comptime because its return type is comptime-only, but does not explain why that is.
5. `this.predicate(result)` - here result is an optional. since you tested for null above, you can safely use `result.?` here or you can change the code so result is no longer an optional with `orelse`:

   ```
   const result = (try this.iterator.next()) orelse return null;
   ```

Now the tests will pass

---

Info about the compiler bug:

```
thread 1531026 panic: zig compiler bug: GenericPoison
Unable to dump stack trace: debug info stripped
zsh: abort      zig test src/utils/iterator.zig
```

> zig compiler bug

This message indicates that the error is a bug in the zig compiler; you should never see it. A compiler bug can either indicate:

- Code that should not compile, but the error is not caught and displayed correctly - this is a bug in the compiler
- Code that should compile, but there is a bug in the compiler preventing it from compiling

Here, the code should cause a compile error about `fn(u32) bool` not being assignable to `fn(anytype) bool`, but there is a bug in the compiler somewhere causing it to say `GenericPoison` instead

Expected error message:

```
a.zig:xx:xx: error: expected type 'fn(anytype) bool', found 'fn(u32) bool'
```

Minimal repro:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn iterWhile(
    predicate: fn (anytype) bool,
) void {
    _ = predicate;
}

test "iter while" {
    iterWhile(isOneDigit);
}

fn isOneDigit(value: u32) bool {
    return value < 10;
}
```

Issue report: [#14052](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/14052), maybe related to the comment on [#12373](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/12373)